# Can I compute camera pose from image with known scale?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a photo taken from a camera (whose focal length, principle point, and distortion coefficients I know). The photo has a 8cm x 8cm post-in on a table and the center of the post-it is the origin `(0, 0)` again in cm. I've also indicated the positive-y axis on the post-it.

[image]

From this information is it possible to compute the location of the camera and the vector in which the camera is looking in Python using OpenCV? If someone has a snippet of code that does that (assuming you know the coordinates of the post-it corners already) that would be amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenCV's [solvePnP](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d) specifying SOLVEPNP_IPPE_SQUARE in the flags. With only 4 points (and a postit) the solution will be quite sensitive to how accurately you mark their images, so ask yourself whether you really need the camera pose and location for your application, and how accurately. E.g., if you just want to make a flat CG "sticker" stay fixed on the table while the camera moves, all you need is estimating a homography, a much simpler task.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like you have all the information required. The marker you use can be easily segmented. Shape analysis will provide corners. I did something similar to get basic eyesight tracking:

[image]

Here is a [complete example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqSki5NjeM4).

Segmentation result for the example:
[image]

Please notice, accuracy really matters, so it might be useful to rely on several sets of points.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the segmentation, like I mentioned I know the coordinates of the post-it corners already. More looking for how to go from that to camera position and look vector.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to show a similar approach (with eye sight direction) works, but let me check the concept and get some results :)